# Keras MSE Loss with Two Outputs

Tags: python, keras

I have a model whose output layer is `Dense(2)` so my output is a list of 2 floats.

I found a similar example on [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/#meansquarederror-class)

```
>>> y_true = [[0., 1.], [0., 0.]]
>>> y_pred = [[1., 1.], [1., 0.]]
>>> # Using 'auto'/'sum_over_batch_size' reduction type.  
>>> mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
>>> mse(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
0.5
```

Based on the output of the example, I think it computes the MSE like this

```
first_MSE = mse(y_true[0], y_pred[0])
second_MSE = mse(y_true[1], y_pred[1])
mse = (first_MSE + second_MSE) / 2
```

Doing the above I get 0.5 as in the example. Is that what it really happens under the hood?

Comment: Having `Dense(2)` does not mean you have two outputs. You have one output with a shape of `(2,)`

Comment: @Frightera You're right I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MeanSquaredError is first computed as the mean over the last axis and then the mean over the batch.

Mean over last axis of the squared difference is computed here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7ec285825c713af9bc741b8b65d09dd160ec8806/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1213

The class `MeanSquaredError` uses the default reduction which does the mean over the batch losses, here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7ec285825c713af9bc741b8b65d09dd160ec8806/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/losses_utils.py#L264